# Complex SQL for multiple branches

Tags: mysql

I need to do a report on 3 branches I have showing products sold PER branch. Although some products are not in all branches, in which case I have a main branch.

I have these tables

```
ORDER
id_order
id_branch

DETAILORDER
id_detail
id_order
id_product
quant

BRANCH
id_branch
id_mainbranch
```

I would like to have a report like this:

```
id_product   quantsold_IN_branch1  quantsold_IN_branch2   SOLDTOTAL
ID1                    8                   12                20
ID2                    9                   13                22
...
```